How large are joeys when they leave the mother kangaroo's pouch?
It makes sense to me that the mother stops letting the joey back in when it gets too large to carry. I didn't want to just accept this without proof, so I went looking for information online. I found two okay sources that say the joey is not allowed back into the pouch when it is ~20% of the mother’s weight  [1, 2]. Does anyone know where that number comes from, or have a better source for it?
EDIT: I found that the second source I gave is word-for-word copied from the book Kangaroos by Terence Dawson, available on the Internet Archive. The original also includes some interesting graphs showing young's development in terms of both mass and time. Unfortunately, he does not provide a source for the 20% claim.

Harder to find the answer than you might think, and I'm still not sure that I have the full answer to this.
However, there are quite a few species within the Macropodidae, of which only 4 are commonly called Kangaroo. These are the larger species within the Macropodidae; namely the Red Kangaroo (Osphranter rufus), the Eastern Grey Kangaroo (Macropus giganteus), the Western Grey Kangaroo (Macropus fuliginosus) and the Antilopine Kangaroo (Osphrantus antilopinus).
The studies I found all look at the reproductive biology of the Western and/or Eastern Grey Kangaroo. Fortunately mostly by CSIRO scientists (Australian Government funding), and as such the results are free to read (as far as I can tell). Poole (1975)1 (abstract; full text PDF link on right hand side of page) found that the age of last exit from the pouch in Eastern and Western Grey Kangaroos was about 320 days. Arnold et al (1991)2 provided growth curves from estimated age after leaving pouch permanently with equations to suit:
For females:
$$Y = 33.85(1-exp^{-0.00104age})$$
And males:
$$ Y= 121.43(1-exp^{0.00028age}) $$
Figure 3 in Arnold et al indicates a weight of about 5 - 7 kg for both males and females at age ~1 year (or roughly the age at which they leave the pouch), and that females have a maximum weight of about 35 kg, so a maximum of abut 20% of maternal weight.
Hamilton et al (2010)3 found that log of weight of weaning scales across mammalian groups, so you can probably apply these measures across the different species.
Refs:

Poole W. E. 1975. Reproduction in the two species of grey kangaroos, Macropus Giganteus (Shaw) and M. Fuliginosus (Desmarest). II. Gestation, parturition and pouch life. Aust. J. Zool. 23, 333–353 10.1071/ZO9750333

Arnold, G.W., Grassia, A., Steven, D.E., & Weeldenburg, J.R. (1991). Population ecology of western grey kangaroos in a remnant of wandoo woodland at Baker's Hill, southern Western Australia. Wildlife Research, 18, 561-575.

Hamilton MJ, Davidson AD, Sibly RM, Brown JH. Universal scaling of production rates across mammalian lineages. Proc Biol Sci. 2011 Feb 22;278(1705):560-6. doi: 10.1098/rspb.2010.1056. Epub 2010 Aug 26. PMID: 20798111; PMCID: PMC3025672



A fascinating and educated answer! What do you mean by "...log of weight..." in the last paragraph?

@Arrow This will be Logarithm in base-10, also called common log, so often written without the base as most scientists use base-10 and only specify others as needed.

If you say "log of [x] scales across mammalian groups", you don't need to know whether the statement refers to log_10, log_e ['natural' or ln()], or any other base, because these measures differ only by multiplicative constants ...
